# Confused about a sentence

Tags: word-usage

How do you use 'Hope ' in a  sentence where you want the person to know that someone is in hope that he would help him. 
Is this sentence correct- 
He is holding on hope against you.

Pls clarify. 
Thanks

Comment: I'm afraid that I can't work out which person you are talking to. Could you give us a bit more information? A good idea might be to label one person A, the other B and rewrite the request using those labels.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  So,  I am talking to person A and I want to tell person A that I think person  B is having some hopes from him, ie person A.  So would this sentence be right? -> He is holding on hope against you.   Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There are many options for you.  Here a just a few:

> John is ***holding out hope*** that you will help him.
>
> John is ***holding onto hopes*** that you will help him.
>
> John is ***keeping his hopes up*** that you will help him.
>
> John is still ***hoping*** that you will help him.
>
> John is still ***hopeful*** that you will help him.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like Person B has [pinned her hopes on](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/pin-one-s-hopes-on) Person A.

Comment: I like that, "A, B has pinned her hopes on you, I hope you can help her."

Answer (score 0):

> How do you use 'Hope ' in a sentence where you want the person to know
>   that someone is in hope that he would help him. Is this sentence
>   correct- He is holding on hope against you.

**hold out hope** is an idiom:  [TFD](http://www.longmandictionariesusa.com/laad/dictionary#hold_1)

> To maintain hope that something will happen or be the case, especially
>   when it does not seem likely. Often used in negative constructions,
>   and often used with modifiers like "much," "any," "little," etc.,
>   before the word "hope."

Your sentence grammatically would be:

He is **holding out hope** that you would help him.

Comment: Ok,  so is this correct -  he is holding out hope on you.

Comment: @Ritz No, "Holding out hope on" someone is just not colloquial English. "Holding out hope _that_" something will happen is as is "pinned her hope on you" as in Joshua Kaden's answer and my comment on it. I think you need to rework your sentence.